# Load array of doubles in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have this code, (sorry for flooding you with a lot of it) I am trying to make it so every time the user presses the done button on the keyboard everything updates and the data is stored as an array in `NSUserDefaults`. I have created a load button for test purposes ( obviously I will want it to do more than println but that will do for now) I think it is saving but can't be sure because loading it causes the app to crash. My question is how can I save this data then load it as an array that I can then pluck the data out and use each value to repopulate my textfields?
Thank you

```
var dateKey = String(701)
var values = [Double]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

dateLabel.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(dateKey)

}

//KeyboardDoneButton

@IBAction func keyboardDoneButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.resignFirstResponder()

    var allowanceRateKey01:Float64=(allowanceRate01.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var allowanceRateKey02:Float64=(allowanceRate02.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var allowanceRateKey03:Float64=(allowanceRate03.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var allowanceRateKey04:Float64=(allowanceRate04.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var allowanceRateKey05:Float64=(allowanceRate05.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var allowanceRateKey06:Float64=(allowanceRate06.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var allowanceRateKey07:Float64=(allowanceRate07.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey01:Float64=(howmany01.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey02:Float64=(howmany02.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey03:Float64=(howmany03.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey04:Float64=(howmany04.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey05:Float64=(howmany05.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey06:Float64=(howmany06.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var howmanyKey07:Float64=(howmany07.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var aR01 = allowanceRateKey01 ?? 0.0
    var aR02 = allowanceRateKey02 ?? 0.0
    var aR03 = allowanceRateKey03 ?? 0.0
    var aR04 = allowanceRateKey04 ?? 0.0
    var aR05 = allowanceRateKey05 ?? 0.0
    var aR06 = allowanceRateKey06 ?? 0.0
    var aR07 = allowanceRateKey07 ?? 0.0
    var hM01 = howmanyKey01 ?? 0.0
    var hM02 = howmanyKey02 ?? 0.0
    var hM03 = howmanyKey03 ?? 0.0
    var hM04 = howmanyKey04 ?? 0.0
    var hM05 = howmanyKey05 ?? 0.0
    var hM06 = howmanyKey06 ?? 0.0
    var hM07 = howmanyKey07 ?? 0.0

    //Calculations

    var totalValue01:Float64=aR01 * hM01
    var totalValue02:Float64=aR02 * hM02
    var totalValue03:Float64=aR03 * hM03
    var totalValue04:Float64=aR04 * hM04
    var totalValue05:Float64=aR05 * hM05
    var totalValue06:Float64=aR06 * hM06
    var totalValue07:Float64=aR07 * hM07

    total01.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue01)
    total02.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue02)
    total03.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue03)
    total04.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue04)
    total05.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue05)
    total06.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue06)
    total07.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalValue07)

    //Grand Total
    var grandTotal:Float64=totalValue01 + totalValue02 + totalValue03 + totalValue04 + totalValue05 + totalValue06 + totalValue07
    total08.text = String(format: "%.2f", grandTotal)

    values = [aR01, aR02, aR03, aR04, aR05, aR06, aR07, hM01, hM02, hM03, hM04, hM05, hM06, hM07, totalValue01, totalValue02, totalValue03, totalValue04, totalValue05, totalValue06, totalValue07, grandTotal]


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(values, forKey: "array01")

    println(values)



}

@IBAction func loadValues(sender: AnyObject) {

    values = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("array01") as [Double]
    println(values)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Archiver instead of storing the straight array? Likely it has to be (or at least convention call for it to be) some form of `NSData` before it's committed to the `NSUserDefaults`

```
func saveData() {
    var values = [aR01, aR02, aR03, aR04, aR05, aR06, aR07, hM01, hM02, hM03, hM04, hM05, hM06, hM07, totalValue01, totalValue02, totalValue03, totalValue04, totalValue05, totalValue06, totalValue07, grandTotal]

    var valuesAsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(values)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(valuesAsData, forKey: "values")
}

func recallData() {
    let valuesAsData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("values") as? NSData

    if valuesAsData != nil {
        if let values = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(valuesAsData) as? [Double] {
            // Do something with your array
        }

    }
}
```